# Angular 7 with Jquery Plugin

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

Hi i write a plugin to show alerts after events. It's name is tdAlert. It works fine in some of my components but it doesn't work in some of my other components.

This one is working component;

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from '../../../services/shared';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'admin-header',
    templateUrl: './header.html',
    providers: [SharedService]
})

export class AdminHeaderComponent {
    errorMsg: string;

    kullanici: any;

    constructor(private service: SharedService, private router: Router) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        $("#tdAlertMessage").tdAlert({
            title: 'blah blah',
            message: 'blah blah.',
            time: 2
        });

        this.service.getCurrentUser().subscribe((resData) => {
            if (resData != null) {
                this.kullanici = resData;
            }
        }, resError => this.errorMsg = resError);

        $('#txtMainSearch').typeahead({
            source: [
                'Kategoriler',
                'Kategoriler (Dil)',
                'İçerikler',
                'Kullanıcılar'
            ],
            items: 4
        });
    }
}
```

And it doesn't work in this component, it gives "jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__(...).tdAlert is not a function" error.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { GaleriService } from "../../services/galeri";
import { SharedService } from '../../services/shared';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as $ from "jquery";

@Component({
    templateUrl: './index.html',
    providers: [GaleriService, SharedService]
})

export class AdminGaleriIndexComponent {
    errorMsg: string;
    GaleriList: {};

    insertShow: boolean;

    callTable: boolean;

    constructor(private service: GaleriService, private sharedService: SharedService, private router: Router) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.callTable = true;
        this.UserRightsControl($("#hdnModel").val());
    }

    onDelete(id) {
        this.service.getSil(id).subscribe((resData) => {
            if (resData == true) {
                $("#tdAlertMessage").tdAlert({
                    title: 'blah blah',
                    message: 'blah blah.',
                    time: 2
                });

                $("a.dltLink.active-dlt").parent("li").parent("ul").parent("div").parent("td").parent("tr").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }
            else {
                $("#tdAlertMessage").tdAlert({
                    title: 'blah blah',
                    message: 'blah blah.',
                    time: 2
                });
            }
        }, resError => this.errorMsg = resError);
    }

    UserRightsControl(Model: any) {
        this.sharedService.getHasRight(Model, "i").subscribe((iRight) => {
            this.insertShow = iRight;

            if (this.callTable == true) {
                this.service.getIndex().subscribe((resData) => {
                    this.GaleriList = resData;
                    this.callTable = false;

                    setTimeout(() => {
                        $(".data-table").dataTable({
                            "bJQueryUI": true,
                            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                            "sDom": '<""l>t<"F"fp>'
                        });

                        if ($(".dropdown-menu").first().find("a").length <= 0) {
                            $(".btn-group").remove();
                        }

                        $(document).on("click", ".fg-button", () => {
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                this.UserRightsControl($("#hdnModel").val());
                            }, 1);
                        });
                    }, 1);
                }, resError => this.errorMsg = resError);
            }

            setTimeout(() => {
                if ($(".dropdown-menu").first().find("a").length <= 0) {
                    $(".btn-group").remove();
                }
            }, 1);

        }, resError => this.errorMsg = resError);
    }
}
```

And this is my app.module.ts file;

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare global {
    interface JQuery {
        tdAlert(obj: any): JQuery;
        dataTable(obj: any): JQuery;
        typeahead(obj: any): JQuery;
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'ang-app',
    templateUrl: './app.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
    ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```

Please help me. I couldn't find any solution about 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways for doing this:
for example, u can add the jquery as a script in ur index.html and then whenever u want to use jquery in ur component just add:

```
declare const $: any;
```

at top of ur class, **instead of ur `import * as $ from "jquery";`** then it will work perfectly.

## note

if u want to use it with 3rd party plugins just install it by npm like this:

```
npm install jquery
npm install @types/jquery -D // in case u r using ts and want to have some autocomplete ability
```

then define a js file with this content:

```
var jQuery = require('jquery');
var $ = jQuery;
```

add the js file in ur index.html and then add the other 3rd party plugins script tag after it, this method works for me, but u can also search for other choices and ways to doing it

Comment: isn't "import * as $ from "jquery";" same as "declare const $: any;" ? Cause i add iit to top of my component and dataTable plugin works fine but tdAlert doesn't work. when i use it dataTable function is also giving same error.

Comment: did u remove the import section? and, r u using a 3rd party jquery plugin?

Comment: which import section? i use my plugins. i write them.

Comment: import * as $ from "jquery";

Comment: yes when i change it with "declare const $: any;" dataTable doesn't work too.

Comment: ohhhh, u wanna use dataTable? why don't u use this? https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome  I tried it before in some of my projects and it was pretty good actually

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195825/discussion-between-thrashead-and-seyed-ali-roshan).